# How to display woocommerce product details on wp page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using elementor page builder for my site, I have set up a woocommerce.

I need help creating a page exactly as shown in the image below.
The page contains a simple form but the title of the page is the title of the product whose id is in the URL which is "?rid=6403"

if you change the id the title will be changed accordingly.
How can develop this page? Please help

Thanks in advanced..

[image]

Comment: Are you using Elementor free or Pro?

Comment: I am using elementor pro

Comment: Then ask their support. They would give you a better answer.

Comment: I am having a word with them, But I want to understand how can I do it without elementor?

Comment: The website in the image is not developed on elementor, but still they managed to do it.. I would like to know how.